# Dynamic list of hamburger menu buttons

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, template10

I want to create a `HamburgerMenu` from a dynamic list of items, preferably I'd like to bind something like a `ListBox` with a template to a list on my view model, and have the menu items appear dynamically.  (See: http://bit.ly/1Lac78E).

Attempting to add anything to the `PrimaryButtons` (or probably the `SecondaryButtons`) collection other than `HamburgerButtonInfo` causes an error.  Presumably because those collections are declared as:

```
PrimaryButtons = new ObservableItemCollection<HamburgerButtonInfo>(); 
SecondaryButtons = new ObservableItemCollection<HamburgerButtonInfo>();
```

So is it possible to do this with the Template10 hamburger menu, without using code-behind like in this question: [UWP Template 10 create a dynamic hamburgermenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231721/uwp-template-10-create-a-dynamic-hamburgermenu/35244589)?

**UPDATE**

To clarify, I am trying to create a navigation menu (using the Hamburger menu template) similar to the Mail and Calendar app, where there is a dynamic list of folders and items in the folders.

[image]

Comment: @MirkoBellabarba Yes, template10 is "natively" MVVM.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's not mandatory. Have you tried to bind the primary buttons to a list/ObservableCollection of HamburgerButtonInfo declared in your ViewModel?

Comment: That's an interesting idea, the downside though is I would have to create the buttons manually (via code), rather than be able to use data templates, right?

Answer (score 1):

First, I am not sure this is very smart in the first place.

But here's how you can do it.

```
public class MainPage:Page
{
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.PrimaryButtons = Views.Shell.HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons;
        ViewModel.SecondaryButtons = Views.Shell.HamburgerMenu.SecondaryButtons;
    }
}

public class MainPageViewModel
{
    Windows.Foundation.Collections.IObservableVector<ICommandBarElement> PrimaryButtons { get; set; }
    Windows.Foundation.Collections.IObservableVector<ICommandBarElement> SecondaryButtons { get; set; }
}
```

Best of luck,
Jerry

Comment: Why do you say it's not very smart?

Comment: I did a dynamic appbar for uwp but I don't have time for now to share the code I'll try to do that tonight

Comment: So this causes a compiler error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Template10.Controls.HamburgerButtonInfo>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ICommandBarElement>'.  Trying to cast it, just gives me a different compiler error telling me that it's not castable.

Comment: @RicardoPons To be clear I want to add items to the hamburger (nav menu) down the right side, not the app bar.  Essentially I want to create something similar to the Mail and Calendar app, where the items in the hamburger menu are a set of folders and items in the folders.  Depending on the user (like in Mail and Calendar) the number and names of folders will be different.